# Using ADSI calls, how to get ms-TS-Allow-Logon attribute value?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adsi

I am trying to retrieve some attributes of a terminal service user(eg.ms-TS-Allow-Logon)  through ADSI.
I tried something like

```
LPOLESTR pszPropertyList [] = {L"ms-TS-Allow-Logon"};
swprintf_s(pszSearchFilter, dwLength, L"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)");
hr = pContainerToSearch->ExecuteSearch(pszSearchFilter,
                                               pszPropertyList,
                                               sizeof(pszPropertyList)/sizeof(LPOLESTR),
                                               &hSearch
                                             );
```

But it doesn't work.
Where can I get the exact attribute names to be passed to an ADSI call for all these terminal service names(like ms-TS-Allow-Logon, ms-TS-Endpoint-Type etc)

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to MSDN [ms-TS-Allow-Logon attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the ldap name for this attribute is msTSAllowLogon

Answer (score 0):

We can get all the attribute names using the ADSI tool that gets shipped along with the activedirectory